# Nsubsitute mocking AS/IS .net

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, npgsql, nsubstitute

I am having hard time mocking `IDbConnection`. I have a method that returns `IDbConnection` but than I have a check to verify if this connection is `NpgsqlConnection` like this:

```
if (conn as NpgsqlConnection == null)
{
    throw new System.Exception("error");
}
```

and while method returns mock object, casting(`as`) returns null and creates an exception. How can I use NSubsiute so it will treat it as `NpgsqlConnection` object?

And second question that is following up, if this one could be resolved is that I am using `BeginBinaryImport` from `NpgsqlConnection` which does not have an interface and I cannot mock it, how can I fake it, so it won't throw an error when used like this `using var importer = conn.BeginBinaryImport("COPY.....` ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to test actually. If you want to test the functionality of `NpgsqlConnection` also, you can create a NpgsqlConnection with a test connection string.

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    // returns NpgsqlConnection with test connection string
    // If you substituted for a class rather than an interface, check that the call to your substitute was on a virtual/abstract member.
    IDbConnection conn = _connectionManager.GetConnection(); 

    if (conn as NpgsqlConnection == null)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("error");
    }

    // functionality
    using (var writer = (conn as NpgsqlConnection).BeginBinaryImport("COPY data (field_text, field_int4) FROM STDIN BINARY"))
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Here. You can make `_connectionManager.GetConnection();` to return a test db connection which is a NpgsqlConnection. So you can test the code.

You can set it up like this:

```
var testConnection = new NpgsqlConnection("TESTCONNECTIONSTRING");
var conn = Substitute.For<ConnectionManager>();
conn.GetConnection().Returns(testConnection);
```

Otherwise, You need **a dependency which abstracts functionality away from calling code**. You don't need to worry too much about what a dependency is doing.

Your code can be something like this instead:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    IDbConnection conn = _connectionManager.GetConnection(); // returns NpgsqlConnection

    _npgsqlConnectionHelper.ValidateConnection(conn);

    _npgsqlConnectionHelper.DoFunctionality(conn);
}
```

Here, you can mock `_npgsqlConnectionHelper`